# Bring a row into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table as my input:

```
Date   | Agent Name | Agent Department | Call ID | Transfer? | TransferToAgent_Dept    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/20 | ABC        | Sales            | 121     | Yes       | Marketing
1/1/20 | XYZ        | Marketing        | 121     | No        | NULL
```

The output that I am looking for is:

```
Date   | Agent Name | Agent Department | Call ID | Transfer? | TransferToAgent | TransferToAgent_Dept
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/20 | ABC        | Sales            | 121     | Yes       | XYZ             | Marketing
```

So the Agent name that currently appears in the row below, I want to bring it up as a column.

Comment: Hum, your output you are looking for seems empty!!!

Comment: There you go! just edited it.

Comment: @Ash . . . I don't get what the rules are.  What if there are three rows?  What if all have `Transfer?` with the same value?  You should be explicit on what you want done.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. If there are multiple transfers, then the corresponding transferred to agent needs to appear in the Transfer To Agent Field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join

```
select 
    a.Date, a.[Agent Name], a.[Agent Department], a.[Call ID], a.[Transfer?], 
    b.[Agent Name] as TransferToAgent, 
    a.TransferToAgent_Dept    
from tbl a
inner join tbl b on a.[Call ID] = b.[Call ID] and a.[Transfer?] = 'Yes'
    and b.[Transfer?] = 'No'
```

Comment: This seems to be working for a single transfer perfectly!
I am kinda confused if it would work for multiple transfers and should there be any sort of condition that needs to be put. 
For example:


Date   | Agent Name | Agent Department | Call ID | Transfer? | TransferToAgent_Dept    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/20 | ABC        | Sales            | 121     | Yes       | Marketing
1/1/20 | XYZ        | Marketing        | 121     | Yes        | Billing
1/1/20 | PQR       |Billing | 121 | No | NULL

Comment: When i worked work with acds like Avaya or Aspect to track transfers we used to rely on date and time of the callid. If you have that, then you will be able to have the lineage of transfers. However if you only have the flag transfer, yes/no, you have no way of being sure of the order of transfers if you have more than 1 transfer. I hope its clear.

Comment: I do have callID I am using callID along with Datetime as a KEY to track transfers and I have gotten upto creating this form of hierarchial output as shown in my example 1. But the requirement wants it all to be in a single row.